# Freemarker removing newlines after macro

Tags: macros, whitespace, freemarker

I would like Freemarker to preserve the newline after calls to my macro.

I've messed with closing the tag `<@test></@test>` with makes no difference. I've also tried to work with the  `body` in the directive but that is null.

Perhaps I could access the template content after the tag and if that is a newline then I can print it. But that seems a bit messy.

My template contains:

```
<@test/> <@test/>

<@test/>

<@test/>
```

Which is prints:

```
test test

test
test
```

But I would like it to print:

```
test test

test

test
```

This is how I've defined the directive:

```
public class TestMacro implements TemplateDirectiveModel {

    @Override
    public void execute(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars, TemplateDirectiveBody body)
            throws TemplateException, IOException {

        env.getOut().append("test");

    }
}
```

This is how I add it to the config:

```
Configuration config = configurer.createConfiguration();
config.setSharedVariable("test", new TestMacro());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `<#ftl strip_whitespace=false/>` if you just want to include all the whitespace in a particular template.

Otherwise if you want to achieve this across all templates, you can set the property on the config

```
config.setWhitespaceStripping(false);
```

If you want to compress some of the whitespace within a template, you can use the `<#compress>...</#compress>` directive.

Answer (score 0):

That's how white space striping works (and this is documented). You can either turn if off completely in the `Configuration`, though then you will end up with a lot of unwanted white-space around `#if`-s etc., or you can add `<#nt>`-s after those tags.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction, but this does not quite answer the question fully.

Comment: I was looking for more details on how to set it on the Configuration. I find examples are always helpful when answering questions.

Comment: That depends on how do you configure FreeMarker, which usually depends on the framework you are using. Usually something like `configuration.setWhitespaceStripping(false);` in Java or `whitespace_stripping=false` in a `.properties` file, etc.